# Flutter: custom drawer with multiple widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

This is a follow up question on my previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52442667/10396137). The last answer helped me to have a desire side drawer with single listview. however, now i am trying to design a complex side navigation something like this:

[image]

As you can see, i am trying to add multiple widgets in a single drawer. can someone please guide me or assist me in getting the desire output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/ibhavikmakwana/FlutterPlayground/blob/master/lib/ui/drawer/NavigationDrawer.dart

Answer (score 3):

You can compose your drawer whatever you want. Everything is a `Widget` =)

```
Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
        child: Text('Custom Header'),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.photo),
        title: Text('First layout'),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Communicate'),
        //without leading =)
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.share),
        title: Text('Share layout'),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

You can, for example, add a `Divider` or something else. You can check official documentation https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/drawer/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This is mine code and now what you have to do is only change the requirement widget and use it widget wise

drawer:
Drawer(

```
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                      child: ListView(
              
              children: <Widget>[
                
                UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  
                  accountName: Text("Akash Kumar", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orangeAccent)),
                  accountEmail: Text("akashsingh@gmail.com", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orangeAccent)),
                  currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/Capture.PNG'),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.trending_up),
                  title: Text("Trending News", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                  title: Text("Favorite News!", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.settings_applications),
                  title: Text("Settings", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
                const Divider(),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                  title: Text("Logout!", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```