# Flutter - remove space between items in ListView

Tags: android, ios, flutter, padding

I am using ListView.builder function to create a list of items. However, the space between each item in iOS is huge (screenshot). Do you know how to remove item? It seems it is by default, because I do not adding it.

code:

**ListView:**

```
return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final model = data[index];
            if (model.path.isEmpty)
              return Divider(color: Colors.grey[500], indent: 40.0);
            else
              return ItemMenu(model.path, model.name);
          }),

);
```

**Item:**

```
return Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Image.asset(path, width: 100, height: 100,color: Colors.grey[500]),
    Text(name, style: MyTextTheme().getLightSmallGrey().copyWith(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700))
  ],
);
```

[image: iOS Simulator screenshot]

Comment: `height: 100` - most likely make it smaller

Comment: Similar kind of problem already solved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441805/how-to-remove-or-manage-space-in-flutter-listview-builder

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya it was because of ListTile which I am not using

Comment: @pskink I would like to keep the icon that big

Comment: It seems like your image has a lot of padding. Could you attach one of those icon to your question?

Comment: @diegoveloper You are right, I tried it with Icon() and padding is gone.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a ListTile widgets as your ListView items, you can add the dense = true option:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    ListTile(
      dense: true,
      ...
    ),
    ListTile(
      dense: true,
      ...
    ),
  ]
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers recommended using `dense: true` but that just made the text smaller in my case and did not actually reduce the spacing between List Items.

**Solution:**
Use `visualDensity` property instead within the `ListTile`.

**Code Example:**
`visualDensity:VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),`

Answer (score 0):

i just resolved that issue but within an image network with "fit" property: Boxfit.cover/fill

Answer (score 0):

To remove these artifacts adapt item height for `devicePixelRatio`:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final pixelRatio = MediaQuery.devicePixelRatioOf(context);
  final desiredHeight = 100.0;
  final h1 = desiredHeight - desiredHeight % pixelRatio;
  final h2 = h1 + pixelRatio;
  final realHeight = h2 - desiredHeight < desiredHeight - h1 ? h2 : h1;
  
  return SizedBox(
    height: realHeight,
    child: ...
  );
}
```